# php combining variables with a hypen in between

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables, combinations

I would like to make a variable from my form that is in the form of the data string in MySQL which looks like yyyy-mm-dd I would like to use the hypens so that it can search for it that way.

```
$year=$_POST['year'};
$mont=$_POST['month'];
$day=$_POST['day'];
$date=$year-$mont-$day;
```

Comment: Although you could glue everything together, I would recommend looking into PHP's specific time and date functions (specifically the `DateTime` class) to generate valid dates and generate output that will always match what you need. Note that `2014-5-20` is not the same as `2014-05-20` and a user might not send input that actually translates to a valid date.

Answer (score 1):

Combining the three variables into one?

```
 //your variables
 $year = $_POST['year'};
 $month = $_POST['month'];
 $day = $_POST['day'];

 //your variables combined
 $date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure it has the correct format of 'yyyy-mm-dd', use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$date = sprintf('%d-%02d-%02d', $_POST['year'], $_POST['month'], $_POST['day']);
```

*This assumes the year is between 1000 and 9999.*

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a format like 2014-04-17?
change this code below

```
$date=$year-$mont-$day;
```

to

```
$date=$year . "-" . $mont . "-" . $day;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways to do this.

```
$date = "$year-$month-$day";

$date = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day;

$date = sprintf('%s-%s-%s', $year, $month, $day);

// Example from the manual, enforces ISO 8601 format
$date = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", $year, $month, $day);
```